# How to download multiple mp4 file in background with progress in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, background-process, nsmutableurlrequest

I stuck from last 2 days on this issue. please help me out.

My requirement is, if I downloading a file in background in second view controller and after download starting I pop to 1st view controller and If I again push to 2nd view controller then that progress should be continue.

Here what happening :

1. I push to second view controller.
2. I started Download using `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSURLConnection`.
3. If I pop to 1st view controller and again go to 2nd view controller then all are showing 0. Means If progress is 34% during pop and again push time its 0% showing in my UI, but download is continuing as usual.

My log also showing perfect but UI its not showing. I tried all SO answers. All are in same problem.

This is my whole code :

In App Delegate Method :

## CTAppDelegate.h

```
@property (copy) void (^backgroundSessionCompletionHandler)();
```

## CTAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    self.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
}
```

## 2ndViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)downloadBackground:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)downloadImage:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *downloadedImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
@end
```

## 2ndViewController.m

```
#import "CTViewController.h"
#import "CTSessionOperation.h"
#import "CTAppDelegate.h"

static NSString *downloadUrl =     @"http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/ladee_9.4.13_nasa_edge_0.jpg";

@interface CTViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperation *downloadOperation;

@end

@implementation CTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.progressView.progress = 0;
    self.downloadedImage.hidden = NO;
    self.progressView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)downloadBackground:(id)sender {
//    [self downloadImageInBackground:YES];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)downloadImage:(id)sender {
    [self downloadImageInBackground:NO];
}

- (void)downloadImageInBackground:(BOOL)background{
   if (self.downloadOperation){
       return;
   }

    CTSessionOperation *operation = [CTSessionOperation new];
    operation.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
    operation.progressAction = ^(double bytesWritten, double bytesExpected){
        double progress = bytesWritten / bytesExpected;
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.progressView.progress = (float) progress;
        });
     };
     operation.completionAction = ^(NSURL *imageUrl, BOOL success){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (success){
                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageUrl path]];
                 self.downloadedImage.image = image;
                 NSLog(@"Done.......");
              }
             self.downloadedImage.hidden = NO;
             self.progressView.progress = 0;
             self.progressView.hidden = YES;
             self.downloadOperation = nil;
         });
     };
     operation.isBackground = background;

     [operation enqueueOperation];
     self.downloadedImage.hidden = YES;
     self.progressView.hidden = NO;
     self.downloadOperation = operation;
  }

  @end
```

## Operation.h

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  typedef void (^CTProgressBlock)(double totalBytesWritten, double bytesExpected);
  typedef void (^CTCompletionBlock)(NSURL *imageUrl, BOOL success);

  @interface CTSessionOperation : NSOperation<NSURLSessionDelegate,    NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>

  @property (nonatomic) NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask;
  @property (nonatomic) NSURLSession *session;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *downloadUrl;
  @property (strong) CTProgressBlock progressAction;
  @property (strong) CTCompletionBlock completionAction;
  @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isBackground;

  - (void)enqueueOperation;
  @end
```

## Operation.m

```
  #import "CTSessionOperation.h"
  #import "CTAppDelegate.h"

  @implementation CTSessionOperation

  - (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue{
         static NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = nil;
         static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
         dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
               operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
               [operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount];
         });

        return operationQueue;
    }

    - (NSURLSession *)session {
         static NSURLSession *session = nil;
         static NSURLSession *backgroundSession = nil;
         static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
         dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
              NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration =  [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
              session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
              NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration
         backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.captech.NSURLSample.BackgroundSession"];
              backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfiguration
                                                      delegate:self
                                                 delegateQueue:nil];
             });

          return self.isBackground ? backgroundSession : session;
    }

    - (void)enqueueOperation{
          [[self operationQueue] addOperation:self];
    }

    #pragma mark - NSOperation

    - (void)start {
         if (!self.isCancelled){
                NSURL *downloadURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.downloadUrl];
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];

                self.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithRequest:request];
                [self.downloadTask resume];
          }
     }

     #pragma mark - NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate
     - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSArray *urls = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
        NSURL *documentsDirectory = [urls objectAtIndex:0];

        NSURL *originalUrl = [[downloadTask originalRequest] URL];
NSURL *destinationUrl = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:[originalUrl lastPathComponent]];
         NSError *error;

        [fileManager removeItemAtURL:destinationUrl error:NULL];
          BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:location toURL:destinationUrl error:&error];
          if (self.completionAction){
                 self.completionAction(destinationUrl, success);
           }
     }

       - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
              if (downloadTask == self.downloadTask && self.progressAction){
              self.progressAction((double)totalBytesWritten, (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
           }
     }

     - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {

     }

    #pragma mark - NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
        if (self.progressAction){
               self.progressAction((double)task.countOfBytesReceived, (double)task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive);
        }

         self.downloadTask = nil;
    }

     #pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate

      - (void)URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSURLSession *)session {
           CTAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CTAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
           if (appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler) {
                 void (^completionHandler)() =  appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler;
             appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil;
    completionHandler();
           }
     }

     @end
```

This is my full code. Please check with this ... :)

Comment: Have a variable in app delegate keep updating it with progress value :) Whenever you come back to second VC just read the data from appdelegate variable display the progress :) add an observer to that appdelagete variable so whenever your request changes the value you will get a chance to update UI :) Thats all :) Simple yet a very crude way to deal with things :)

Comment: Add observer in view will appear and remove in view will disappear :) you wont want to get notified when you are 1st VC isn't it :) Lastly, its a quick fix though, nothing wrong in it but just not a great way to do it :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Please can u provide me some pinch of code what i have to do. Actually I am not getting above points. :)

Comment: I'll try providing you a cleaner code then the one that I mentioned above :) gimme 10 min :)

Comment: Can you give code for got to the second view controller from first view controller?

Comment: @PayalManiyar : Please check the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have dealt with download a little different from how you are doing it :)

Here is how I would handle it :)

1.Declare a NSOperation class and move the code to download the file to this class

2.Declare a protocol in your NSOpertaion class which will inform the current download status to whoever confirms to this protocol

3.In your second VC start the NSOpertaion and opt for the delegate :) and update your progress accordingly

4. In viewWillDisappear of your secondVC remove it as delegate and add it back as delegate to NSOperation in ViewWillAppear of secondVC

Here is a little bit of code for the same :)

*downloadAssets.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol AssetDownloadStatusProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)updateStatusWithValue:(float) progress;
@end

@interface downloadAssets : NSOperation
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<AssetDownloadStatusProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *urlToDownload;
-(id)initWithURL:(NSString *)url;
@end
```

*downloadAssets.m*

```
    @implementation downloadChatAssets

-(id)initWithURL:(NSString *)url{
    self=[super init];
    self.urlToDownload = url;
    appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return self;
}

- (void)main {
    // a lengthy operation
    @autoreleasepool {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            if (self.isCancelled) {
                appdelegate.downloadingOperation = nil;
                return;
            }
            else{
                NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                AFURLSessionManager *manager = ... //start downloading

                NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:URLRequest uploadProgress:nil downloadProgress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {
                    if (self.isCancelled) {
                        appdelegate.downloadingOperation = nil;
                        return;
                    }
                    self.progressAmount = downloadProgress.fractionCompleted;
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.delegate updateStatusWithValue:self.progressAmount];
                    });
                } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    //handle completion here
                }];

                [dataTask resume];
            }
        });
    }
}
@end
```

*AppDelegate.h*

```
@property (nonatomic, Strong) NSOperation *downloadingOperation;
```

*SecondVC.h*

```
@interface SecondVC : UIViewController <AssetDownloadStatusProtocol>
```

*SecondVC.m*

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    if(appdelegate.downloadingOperation) {
          appdelegate.downloadingOperation.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    if(appdelegate.downloadingOperation) {
           appdelegate.downloadingOperation.delegate = nil;
    }
}

-(void)updateStatusWithValue:(float)progress{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update your progress here
        [self.progressView updateProgressBarWithProgressValue:progress];
    });
}
```

Thats it :)

start the download operation whenever you want :)

```
appdelegate.downloadingOperation = yourDownloaderOperation;
[yourDownloaderOperation start];
```

You wanna stop it say

```
[yourDownloaderOperation stop];
```

Have morethan one download operation ?? Consider using NSOperationQueue or Array to hold NSOperations in appdelegate :)

**EDIT**

As per your request in comment, you can hold the reference to CTOperation in your appDelegate.

```
@property (nonatomic, Strong) CTOperation *downloadingOperation;
```

You dont need to declare a protocol as you have already declared completion block and progressActionBlock :)

All you have to do is to, check in your SecondVC viewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:YES];
        if(appdelegate.downloadingOperation) {
              appdelegate.downloadingOperation.progressAction = ^(double bytesWritten, double bytesExpected){
    double progress = bytesWritten / bytesExpected;
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.progressView.progress = (float) progress;
    });
 };
 appdelegate.downloadingOperation.completionAction = ^(NSURL *imageUrl, BOOL success){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         if (success){
             UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageUrl path]];
             self.downloadedImage.image = image;
             NSLog(@"Done.......");
          }
         self.downloadedImage.hidden = NO;
         self.progressView.progress = 0;
         self.progressView.hidden = YES;
         self.downloadOperation = nil;
     });
 };
        }
    }

    -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
        if(appdelegate.downloadingOperation) {
               appdelegate.downloadingOperation.progressAction = nil;
               appdelegate.downloadingOperation.completionAction = nil;
        }
    }
```

and in your downloadImageInBackground method rather than `self.downloadOperation = operation;` say `appdelegate.downloadingOperation = operation;

**Disclaimer**

Please note code provided in this answer is only for the purpose of explaining concept. May I have syntactic or symmentic errors. Please refrain from blindly copy pasting.

Simple right ??? Have doubts, ping me :) Happy coding :)

Comment: I did the Operation class. but i need only saving the progress status . Yes its more than one download opereation. Wait i am update my question with code.

Comment: @s-r-nayak : I am lost a bit in your code. You have declared NSOperation inside your viewController, when you popout from SecondVC its properties including NSOperations will be removed. So though your operation continues you lost the reference to it. And when you come back to the SecondVC your operation property is always nil. How are you planning to get the reference to executing operation back ??? You dont have reference to it neither in appdelegate nor do you have NSOperationQueue. How can you expect the operation to inform you about progress when u comeback second time buddy ???

Comment: Ok, Then what I have to do. please guide me in code ?

Comment: @s-r-nayak : I have clearly wriitten in the code posted above, please read it carefully. If you can see I am holding the reference to the NSOperation I created in SecondVC in appdelegate.downloadingOperation property

Comment: @s-r-nayak : Please wait I believe while updating my answer I have deleted few lines of code lemme update the same :)

Comment: @s-r-nayak : Please have a look at the updated code now :) Still have doubts please ask me :)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I got ur code. But According to my coding, whatever u got the issue, just tell me that one, what i have to do with my code. :)

Comment: @s-r-nayak : Simple buddy :) Just hold the reference to your CTOperation in appdelegate :) In view will appear check if that property in appDelegate is nil or not :) and then set the operation.completionAction and operation.progressAction thats all :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110369/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-s-r-nayak).