# call NSUrlSessionConnection delegate methods when viewcontroller is deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have a situation like I'm calling a web service to GET some information from server. Immediately the viewcontroller is navigated to another viewcontroller. When the service call responds with some data, the Viewcontroller is not alive. So, How to handle this situation. Please help.

Comment: create a NSOperation, ask it to download the data from server :) start the operation in your viewcontroller :) Even if your viewController is deallocated NSOperation will download the data for you :) Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882179/how-to-download-multiple-mp4-file-in-background-with-progress-in-ios/36882939#36882939 not a same question though you might use the concept :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store data fetched in one VC, that dealocating, you can try create some manager,as singleton, which will fetch data, and the you can use it in another VC, when its will be ready(fetched)